# IO Monads: GHC Implementation Meaning vs. Mathematical Meaning

Tags: haskell, monads

Consider

```
ioFunction :: String -> IO ()
ioFunction str = do putStrLn str
                    putStrLn "2"
```

Here, `ioFunction`, from a mathematical point of view, is a function that takes one input and returns a value of type `IO ()`. I presume it means nothing else. That is, from a mathematical point of view, this function returns a value and nothing else; in particular, it doesn't print anything.

So does this mean that the way Haskell uses the IO monad for imperative side-effects (in this case: that running this function will first print `str` and then print "2", in that order) is **purely a GHC implementation detail** that has nothing to do with the mathematical (and in some sense even the Haskell) meaning of the term?

**EDIT:** To make this question clearer, what I mean to ask is, for example, is there any difference from the **mathematical point of view** between the following two functions:

```
ioFunction1 :: String -> IO ()
ioFunction1 str = do putStrLn str
                     putStrLn "2"


ioFunction2 :: String -> IO ()
ioFunction2 str = do return ()
```

It seems the answer is no, for -- from the mathematical point of view -- they both take as input a `String` and return a value (presumably, the same value) of type `IO ()`. Is this not the case?

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you mean. Monads can be used for instance to carry a *hidden* state so to speak and indeed enforce order in execution. The IO monad has in my opinion much in common with the state monad except that it hides all kinds of undeterministic behavior an operating system inherently has.

Comment: What I'm saying is: from a GHC point of view, ioFunction first prints `str` and then prints "2". Yet from a mathematical point of view, this function only take a `String` and returns `() :: IO ()`. Hence the fact that we happen to use the IO monad for side effects in Haskell is in some sense arbitrary, and has nothing to do with the intrinsic meaning of a (mathematical) monad (of type IO).

Comment: No the function does not return `()`, it returns an IO monad (that is here a function) and that monad will eventually return `()`. That is something different. And in fact the IO has some *intrensic* mathematical meaning.

Comment: `() :: IO ()` is a type error. `()` has type `()`.

Comment: Yes -- you're right. It returns a value of type `IO ()`. So how is that value a function though? And from a purely mathematical point of view, what is this value?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The function does not return "an IO monad". There's only one IO monad, and it's not a value. It's a type constructor (of kind `* -> *`) together with an `instance` declaration.

Comment: @melpomene: yeah indeed. I chose my words poorly.

Comment: @George I don't think it is a function.

Comment: @melpomene: From a mathematical perspective, does the value that is returned by this function encode anything that has anything to do with those `putStrLn` calls? I know that, from GHC's perspective, those `putStrLn` calls are definitely part of this function's meaning. But from the mathematical perspective, they could just as easily be ignored, isn't this the case?

Comment: Define "mathematical perspective". There is more than one. The value returned by `putStrLn "2"` has  an action that prints `2` encoded in it (otherwise your program wouldn't be able to print anything).  It's a fact. You can build a mathematical apparatus to describe and study this and similar facts. It probably would be different from the one that deals with functions and pure computations.

Comment: All this discussion misses the point of the mathematical definition of "monad", which is used to encapsulate side effects. See my answer how this definition can be brought in.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798648/how-to-view-higher-order-functions-and-io-actions-from-a-mathematical-perspectiv .

Answer (score 5):

> Here, `ioFunction`, from a mathematical point of view, is a function that takes one input and returns a value of type `IO ()`. I presume it means nothing else.

Yes. Exactly.

> So does this mean that the way Haskell uses the `IO` monad for imperative side-effects (in this case: that running this function will first print str and then `print "2"`, in that order) is purely a GHC implementation detail that has nothing to do with the mathematical (and in some sense even the Haskell) meaning of the term?

Not quite. From a mathematical (set-theory) standpoint, I would assume "same" means structurally identical. Since I don't know what makes up a value of `IO ()`, I can't say anything about whether two values of that type are the same or not.

In fact, this is by design: by making `IO` opaque (in the sense that I don't know what constitutes an `IO`), GHC prevents me from ever being able to say that one value of type `IO ()` is equal to another. The only things I can do with `IO` is exposed through functions like `fmap`, `(<*>)`, `(>>=)`, `mplus`, etc.

Comment: @George Yep. I am of the opinion this should be one of the first things discussed about `IO` - the fact you _can't_ and _shouldn't_ be able to say anything about what structurally makes up an `IO` action.

Comment: @George I'd say that, since IO is opaque, one could have an IO "model" (i.e. a semantics) where all IO actions (of the same type) are equal, e.g `print 5 === return ()`. Essentially, we take `IO a = Const () a`. This would be a trivial IO model which should satisfy all the wanted laws (I guess). This is what you seem to be mentioning in the question. However, IO does not have to be implemented in this (useless) way, and more meaningful models/semantics exist. When dealing with all the possible models, we can not regard `print 5` to be equivalent to `return ()`.

Answer (score 4):

I always find it helpful to consider a simplified “imperative-language source code” implementation of the `IO` monad:

```
data IO :: * -> * where
   PutStr :: String -> IO ()
   GetLine :: IO String
   IOPure :: a -> IO a
   IOSeq :: IO a -> IO b -> IO b
   ...
   LaunchMissiles :: IO ()
```

Then what `ioFunction` is quite clearly a proper, sensible function in the mathematical sense:

```
ioFunction str = do putStrLn str
                    putStrLn "2"
               = putStr (str++"\n") >> putStrLn "2\n"
               = IOSeq (PutStr (str++"\n")) (PutStrLn "2\n")
```

This is simply a data structure representing effectively some source code of an imperative language. `ioFunction` places the given argument in a specific spot in the result structure, so it's mathematically very much not just a trivial *“return `()` and nothing else (something may happen but it's a GHC implementation detail)”*.

The value is indeed completely different for `ioFunction2`:

```
ioFunction2 str = do return ()
                = return ()
                = IOPure ()
```

---

> how do we know they are different in this sense?

That's a good question. Practically speaking, you know it by *executing* both programs and observing that they cause different effects, hence they [must have been different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). This is more than a little awkward of course – “observing what happens” isn't maths, it's physics, and the observation would scientifically require that you execute twice under exact the same environment conditions.

Worse, even with pure values that are generally taken to be mathematically the same you can observe different behaviour: `print 100000000` will immediately cause the side-effect, whereas `print $ last [0..100000000]` takes a significant pause (which, if you follow it with a time-printing command, can actually yield different text output).

But these issues are unavoidable in a real-world context. It hence makes only sense that Haskell's does not specify any structure on IO that could with mathematical rigour be checked for equality from within the language. So, in quite some sense you really *can't* know that `putStrLn str >> putStrLn "2"` is not the same as `return ()`.

And indeed they *might* be the same. It is conceivable to make a even simpler toy implementation of `IO` than the above thus:

```
data IO :: * -> * where
   IONop :: IO ()
   IOHang :: IO a -> IO a
```

and simply map any pure output operation to the no-op (and any input to an infinite loop). Then you would have

```
ioFunction str = do putStrLn str
                    putStrLn "2"
               = IONop >> IONop
               = IONop
```

and

```
ioFunction2 str = return ()
                = IONop
```

This is a bit as if we've imposed an additional axiom on the natural numbers, namely 1 = 0. From that you can then conclude that *every* number is zero.

Clearly though, that would be a totally useless implementation. But something similar could actually make sense if you're running Haskell code in a sandbox environment and want to be utterly sure nothing bad happens. http://tryhaskell.org/ does something like this.

Comment: Well said. But isn't it true that, from a mathematical point of view, both `IOSeq (PutStr (str++"\n")) (PutStrLn "2\n")` and `IOPure ()` are in fact the same value? Or at the very least, how do we know they are different in this sense?

Comment: No, they are not mathematically speaking the same value. _How_ we know they are different is indeed sort of an implementation detail – in such an explicit “imperative code” IO monad, we could simply pattern-match to tell the difference; in compiled GHC this is a bit trickier. You might even devise a “dummy output” implementation where they are in fact the same. At any rate, without knowledge of the implementation you can't _conclude_ they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let us concentrate on the output aspect of the I/O monad. Mathematically speaking, the output (writer) monad is given by an endofunctor *T* with *T(A) = U* × A*, where *U* is a fixed set of characters, and *U** is the set of strings over *U*. Then *ioFunction : U* → T ()*, i.e. *ioFunction : U* → U* × ()*, and *ioFunction(s)* = (s++"\n"++"2\n", ()). By contrast, *ioFunction2(s)* = ("", ()). Any implementation has to respect this difference. The difference is primarily a mathematical one, not an implementation detail.