# How to view higher-order functions and IO-actions from a mathematical perspective?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, io, higher-order-functions, purely-functional

I am trying to understand functional programming from first principles, yet I am stuck on the interface between the pure functional world and the impure real world that has state and side effects. From a mathematical perspective,

- what is a function that returns a function?
- what is a function that returns an IO action (like Haskell's IO type)?

To elaborate: In my understanding, a pure function is a map from domain to co-domain. Ultimately, it is a map from some values in computer memory to some other values in memory. In a functional language, functions are defined declaratively; i.e., they describe the mapping but not the actual computation that needs to be performed on a specific input value; the latter is up to the compiler to derive. In a simplified setting with memory to spare, there would be no computation at runtime; instead, the compiler could create a lookup table for each function already at compile time. Executing a pure program would amount to table lookup. Composing functions thus amounts to building higher-dimensional lookup tables. Of course, the entire point in having computers is to devise ways to specify functions without the need for point-wise table lookup - but I find the mental model helpful to distinguish between pure functions and effects. However, I have difficulty adapting this mental model for higher-order functions:

- For a function that takes another function as argument, what is the resulting first-order function that maps values to values? Is there a mathematical description for it (I'm sure there is, but I am neither a mathematician nor a computer scientist).
- How about a function that returns a function? How can I mentally "flatten" this construct to again get a first-order function that maps values to values?

Now to the nasty real world. Interaction with it is not pure, yet without it, there are no sensible programs. In my simplified mental model above, separating pure and impure parts of a program means that the basis of each functional program is a layer of imperative statements that get data from the real world, apply a pure function to it (do table lookup), and then write the result back to the real world (to disk, to the screen, the network, etc.).

In Haskell, this imperative interaction with the real world is abstracted as *IO actions*, which the compiler sequences according to their data dependency. However, we do not write a program directly as a sequence of imperative IO actions. Instead, there are functions that return IO actions (functions of type `:: IO a`). But to my understanding, these cannot be real functions. What are they? How to best think about them in terms of the mental model outlined above?

Comment: "For a function that takes another function as argument, what is the resulting first-order function that maps values to values?" Functions ARE values, that's the whole point of higher-order functions.

Comment: Yes, functions are values in some specific context, but I haven't figure out exactly when. In Analysis, functions are not values, in Category theory they are. I'm trying to build a mental model to better understand when to speak of  functions in a declarative sense (mapping inputs to outputs), and when to talk about _actions_, which are imperative and not functions. A function that returns an action seems to be the link I am not grokking yet.

Comment: Mathematically, a function from domain C to codomain D is just a subset of the product CxD with the property that, for any c in C, there is exactly one pair in the subset with first coordinate c. Such subsets can absolutely themselves form the domain or codomain of another function.

Comment: You say, "these [functions that return IO actions] cannot be real functions". But this statement is incorrect. Functions that return IO actions are real functions; give them the same input, and they give you the *very* same IO action every time. Now, the runtime system may not do the exact same thing every time it interprets an IO action; that depends on its environment. But the action is the same. If you write `x = getTime` and `y = getTime`, you will never be able to distinguish whether you submitted `x` or `y` to the interpreter on any given occasion.

Comment: `IO` is an action in the sense that it *describes* what action to take. `IO` itself does not *perform* an action, just like `State` is not a *state*, but it describes a *change of state*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mathematically, there's no problem at all with functions that take or return other functions. The standard set-theory definition of a function from set *S* to set *T* is just:

> *f ∈ S → T* means that *f ⊂ S ✕ T* and two conditions hold:
>
> 1. If *s ∈ S*, then *(s, t) ∈ f* for some *t*, and
> 2. if both *(s, t) ∈ f* and *(s, t') ∈ f*, then *t = t'*.
>
> We write *f(s) = t* as a convenient notational shorthand for *(s, t) ∈ f*.

So writing *S → T* just denotes a specific set, and therefore *(A → B) → C* and *A → (B → C)* are again just specific sets.

Of course, for efficiency, we do not represent functions internally in memory as the set of input-output pairs like this, but this is a decent first approximation that you can use if you want a mathematical intuition. (The second approximation takes a lot more work to set up properly, because it uses structures you probably haven't already experienced very much to deal with laziness and recursion in a careful, principled way.)

IO actions are a bit trickier. How you want to think of them may depend a bit on your particular mathematical bent.

One persuasion of mathematician might like to define IO actions as an inductive set, something like:

- If `x :: a`, then `pure x :: IO a`.
- If `f :: a -> b`, then `fmap f :: IO a -> IO b`.
- If `x :: IO a` and `f :: a -> IO b`, then `x >>= f :: IO b`.
- `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`
- `forkIO :: IO a -> IO ThreadId`
- ...and a thousand other base cases.
- We quotient over a few equalities:

  - `fmap id = id`
  - `fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)`
  - `pure x >>= f` = `f x`
  - `x >>= pure . f` = `fmap f x`
  - (and a slightly complicated-to-read one that just says that `>>=` is associative)

In terms of defining the *meaning of a program*, that's enough to specify what "values" the IO family of types can hold. You might recognize this style of definition from the standard way of defining natural numbers:

- *Zero* is a natural number.
- If *n* is a natural number, then *Succ(n)* is a natural number.

Of course, there are some things about this way of defining things that aren't super satisfying. Like: what does any particular IO action *mean*? Nothing in this definition says anything about that. (Though see "Tackling the Awkward Squad" for an elucidation of how you could say what an IO action means even if you take this kind of inductive definition of the type.)

Another kind of mathematician might like this kind of definition better:

> An IO action is isomorphic to a stateful function on a phantom token representing the current state of the universe:
>
> ```
> IO a ~= RealWorld -> (RealWorld, a)
> ```

There are attractions to this kind of definition, too; though, notably, it gets a lot harder to say what the heck `forkIO` does with that kind of definition.

...or you could take the GHC definition, in which case an `IO a` is secretly an `a` if you dig under the covers enough. But, shhh!!, don't tell the inexperienced programmers who just want to escape `IO` and write an `IO a -> a` function because they don't understand how to program using the `IO` interface yet!

Comment: Thanks very much for the insight, makes complete sense. I am inclined to think of IO actions as the mapping between Real Worlds. If I get it right, then, the key point is that functions that return IO actions automatically get the Real World as part of their domain as well, even if this is not part of their type signature.

Comment: @UlrichSchuster Right!

Comment: Actually, not much more is needed to describe the inner workings for `forkIO`: Aquinas Hobor's [thesis](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/techreports/2008/836.pdf) explains how a _"Pthreads style of concurrency"_ can be added to the semantics of a C-like language (which is [more-or-less](http://conal.net/blog/posts/the-c-language-is-purely-functional) Haskell's monadic `IO` type ;-)

Comment: @atravers The semantics given there, on a cursory read, does not appear to be a world-passing semantics, but rather a global state semantics. This difference is, in my opinion, kind of a big deal, and amounts to this: worlds are immutable, global states are mutable. (In particular, `er-cstep-fork` says that θ may change between two individual steps of a single thread, i.e. not as a result of passing a new, updated θ on to the next step of computation.)

Comment: But if θ *didn't* change between two individual steps of a single thread, wouldn't that effectively be the semantics for encapsulated `ST` threads (instead of mutually or outwardly-interacting `IO` threads)?

Answer (score 4):

`IO` is a data structure. E.g. here's a very simple model of `IO`:

```
data IO a = Return a | GetLine (String -> IO a) | PutStr String (IO a)
```

Real `IO` can be seen as being this but with more constructors (I prefer to think of all the `IO` "primitives" in `base` as such constructors). The `main` value of a Haskell program is just a value of this data structure. The runtime (which is "external" to Haskell) evaluates `main` to the first `IO` constructor, then "executes" it somehow, passes any values returned back as arguments to the contained function, and then executes the resulting `IO` action recursively, stopping at the `Return ()`. That's it. `IO` doesn't have any strange interactions with functions, and it's not actually "impure", because *nothing* in Haskell is impure (unless it's unsafe). There is just an entity outside of your program that interprets it as something effectful.

Thinking of functions as tables of inputs and outputs is perfectly fine. In mathematics, this is called the *graph* of the function, and e.g. in set theory it's often taken as the *definition* of a function in the first place. Functions that return `IO` actions fit just fine into this model. They just return values of the data structure `IO`; nothing strange about it. E.g. `putStrLn` might be defined as so (I don't think it actually is, but...):

```
putStrLn s = PutStr (s ++ "\n") (Return ())
```

and `readLn` could be

```
-- this is actually read <$> getLine; real readLn throws exceptions instead of returning bottoms
readLn = GetLine (\s -> Return (read s))
```

both of which have perfectly sensible interpretations when thinking of functions as graphs.

Your other question, about how to interpret higher-order functions, isn't going to get you very far. Functions are values, period. Modeling them as graphs is a good way to think about them, and in that case higher order functions look like graphs which contain graphs in their input or output columns. There's no "simplifying view" that turns a function taking a function or returning a function into a function that takes just values and returns just values. Such a process is not well-defined and is unnecessary.

(Note: some people might try to tell you that `IO` can be seen as a function taking the "real world" as input and outputting a new version of the world. That's really not a good way to think about it, in part because it conflates evaluation and execution. It's a hack that makes *implementing* Haskell simpler, but it makes *using* and thinking about the language a bit of a mess. This data structure model is IMO easier to deal with.)

Comment: Why would you say that thinking of IO actions as functions that update the Real World conflate evaluation with execution? To my understanding, it is exactly this data dependency between successive IO functions that lets Haskell treat them as any other function. In that way, "execution" never enters the picture at all and the entire program stays purely declarative. Actually, this is my main takeaway! I was confused when I read posts and even textbooks saying that some computation is "run" inside some monad. But to my (now confirmed) understanding, there is no execution anywhere in Haskell code

Comment: But that *doesn't* keep the program declarative. If you "open" `IO a := World -> (World, a)`, then an example program may be `main w0 = let (w1, s) = getLine w0 in putStrLn s w1`. When this program executes, a `World` is passed to `main` and evaluation begins. Now, what does evaluating `getLine w0` and `putStrLn s w1` do? The evaluation of those expressions correspond to the program executing effectful actions. Even though they have a "pure" function type, they clearly have an imperative character.

Answer (score 1):

#### What is a function that returns a function?

You were almost there:

> Composing functions thus amounts to building higher-dimensional lookup tables.

Here's a small example, in Haskell:

```
infixr 2 ||

(||)           :: Bool -> (Bool -> Bool)
True  || True  =  True
True  || False =  True
False || True  =  True
False || False =  False
```

Your lookup table would then take the form of a *case-expression*:

```
x || y =  case (x, y) of (True, True)   -> True
                         (True, False)  -> True
                         (False, True)  -> True
                         (False, False) -> False
```

Instead of using tuples:

```
x || y =  case x of True  -> (case y of True  -> True
                                        False -> True)

                    False -> (case y of True  -> True
                                        False -> False)
```

If we now move the parameter `y` into new local functions:

```
(||) x =  case x of True  -> let f y =  case y of True  -> True
                                                  False -> True
                             in f

                    False -> let g y =  case y of True  -> True
                                                  False -> False
                             in g
```

then the corresponding map-of-maps would be:

```
+-------+-----------------------+
| x     | (||) x                |
+-------+-----------------------+
| True  |                       |
|       |   +-------+-------+   |
|       |   | y     | f y   |   |
|       |   +-------+-------+   |
|       |   | True  | True  |   |
|       |   +-------+-------+   |
|       |   | False | True  |   |
|       |   +-------+-------+   |
|       |                       |
+-------+-----------------------+
| False |                       |
|       |   +-------+-------+   |
|       |   | y     | g y   |   |
|       |   +-------+-------+   |
|       |   | True  | True  |   |
|       |   +-------+-------+   |
|       |   | False | False |   |
|       |   +-------+-------+   |
|       |                       |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

So your abstract model can be extended to higher-order functions - they're just maps from some domain to a co-domain consisting of other maps.

---

#### What is a function that returns an I/O action (like Haskell's `IO` type)?

Let's answer the simpler question:

###### What is an I/O action (like Haskell's `IO` type) [from a mathematical perspective]?

...from a mathematical perspective? That's an ironic question, considering mathematics itself is abstract:

> In a preliminary sense, mathematics is abstract because it is studied using highly general and formal resources.
>
> [The Applicability of Mathematics](https://iep.utm.edu/math-app) ([The Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/)).

...that includes abstracting from the existence of an external environment filled with I/O devices and their reliance on effects. This leaves languages like Haskell, which strive to be as closely based on mathematics as possible, with a dilemma:

- > How must interactions between a program and an external environment (consisting of, e.g., input/output-devices, file systems, ...) be described in a programming language that abstracts from the existence of an outside world?
  >
  > [Claus Reinke.](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.9846&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- > One useful property of expressions is referential transparency. In essence this means that if we wish to find the value of an expression which contains a sub-expression, the only thing we need to know about the sub-expression is its value. Any other features of the sub-expression, such as its internal structure, the number and nature of its components, **the order in which they are evaluated** or the colour of the ink in which they are written, are irrelevant to the value of the main expression.
  >
  > [Christopher Strachey.](https://classes.cs.uoregon.edu/14S/cis607pl/Papers/fundamental-1967.pdf)

  <sup>(emphasis by me.)</sup>

So right now (2022 Feb) there is no [practical](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.628.7053&rep=rep1&type=pdf) way to view I/O itself from a mathematical perspective because mathematics just doesn't have one.

I/O: it's the missing [Millennium problem](https://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems)...